# how to convert INT_MIN from int type to vector

Tags: arrays, integer, stdvector

```
vector<int> findSubarray(int a[], int n) {
    int pre=1;
    int suff=1;
  int ans=INT_MIN;
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
       if(pre==0){
           pre=0;
       }
       if(suff==0){
           suff=0;
       }
       pre=pre+a[i];
       suff=suff+a[n-i-1];
       ans=max(ans,max(pre,suff));
       
   }
   return ans;
}
```

the above code is showing an error as:
error: could not convert 'ans' from 'int' to 'std::vector'

even though i tried initialising "ans" with a vector it is still showing an error:
error: conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'std::vector' requested
vector  ans=INT_MIN;
^

Comment: your method is defined to return a `vector<int>`, but `ans` is defined as an `int`. What are you actually trying to do? Ie your method is called `findSubarray` which suggests you want to return an array with multiple values. But you are returing a single value only.

Answer (score 0):

It could be as simple as replacing the final line with:

```
    //...
    std::vector<int> temp = {ans};
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: by replacing the last line the error shown is : conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'std::vector<int>' requested
    vector<int>  ans=INT_MIN;
                                ^